# Empty Form can be send using Validator required

Tags: forms, angular, validation

I have the following form created

```html
<div class="ui raised segment">
  <h2 class="ui header">Demo Form: Sku</h2>
  <form [formGroup]="myForm"
        (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)" class="ui form"
        [class.error]="!myForm.valid && (myForm.dirty || myForm.touched)">
    <div class="field"
         [class.error]="!myForm.valid && (myForm.dirty || myForm.touched)">
      Forms in Angular 141
      <label for="skuInput">SKU</label>
      <input type="text" id="skuInput" placeholder="SKU" name="sku" [formControl]="myForm.controls['sku']">

      <!-- Error Message -->
      <div *ngIf="!myForm.controls['sku'].valid"
           class="ui error message">SKU is invalid</div>
      <div *ngIf="myForm.controls['sku'].hasError('required')"
           class="ui error message">SKU is required</div>
      <!-- End Error Message-->

    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="ui button">Submit</button>
  </form>

</div>
```

The main problem is that I can send the form even if is empty. As soon the page is load if I don't focus on the input (if i do it only once time it works) and I just click the submit button ,the form  get send.

I am creating the form with a form builder :

```js
  myForm : FormGroup;
  private sku: AbstractControl;

  constructor( fb:FormBuilder) {

    this.myForm = fb.group({
      sku : ['' , Validators.required]
    });

    this.sku = this.myForm.controls['sku'];

    this.sku.valueChanges.subscribe(
      (value : String) => {
        console.log('value has change to : ', value);
      }
    )
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(value : string ) {
    console.log(`has enviado :` , value);
  }
```

How can I fix this ?

[image]

PS: I know i could fix it with a reg expression , but the required validator shouldn't work like this I think.

Comment: I think you want to disable submit button if form is invalid: `<button [disabled]="myForm.invalid" ...>`

Comment: @developer033 thanks this works , but still my question is , why with the required field it doesn't catch the error ?

Comment: What do you mean by "catch the error"? Isn't the error being displayed if you do something like: `<div *ngIf="myForm.hasError('required', 'sku')"` or even as you're doing `<div *ngIf="myForm.controls['sku'].hasError('required')"`?

Comment: No that is the problem. If I do as I explain up , just click the submit button without focus on the form , it doesn't give me any error. And in fact in the console when I invoke the function , i receive the "" as the value submitted. I just update the post with a pic

Comment: Well, the way you can prevent the form being submitted blank is the way that I said. Angular doesn't prevent form to be submitted if there are errors on this. It's up to developer to handle his/her cases. Btw, how are you "building" your form? Can you show us?

Comment: @developer033 done

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me [**here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/qe0YYzkcvSReByyTwqkV?p=info). I just added the `[disabled]` on HTML, nothing more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151212/discussion-between-roberto-fernandez-and-developer033).